# Valgrind giving "conditional jump on uninitialized value" on variable with default parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, valgrind

I'm running valgrind on some C++ code I have and it's giving an error saying I have a conditional jump on an uninitialized value. Here is the stretch of code with problems, it's a method (not static).

```
if (debug_ & 0x1) {
    printf("Debugging information...\n");
}
```

But the variable `debug_` is set in the constructor like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(
    AnotherClass* interface,
    int debug) :
    debug_(debug)
{
    //Some other irrelevant stuff


}
```

And the header defines a default argument to that parameter:

```
class MyClass : boost::noncopyable {
  public:
    explicit MyClass(AnotherClass* interface, int debug=0xFF);

  //Other stuff
  private:
    int debug_;
}
```

But for good measure even when I instantiate this class I pass a value to the second argument. What am I missing?

Comment: The value you're passing in might be uninitialized. Eg, `int x; MyClass mc(stuff, x);`

Comment: It might be worth identifying platform, version of GCC (G++) and version of Valgrind.  I'm not sure what you're missing. Have you reduced this to an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))? Have you got other versions of the compiler or Valgrind to try?

Comment: I'll double check the SSCCE criteria soon and get the info on the platform. But I should respond that the value I'm passing in is a hex constant (I've tried integer too):

`MyClass *obj = new MyClass(another_class_instance, 0xFF);`

I just noticed that in addition to the valgrind output mentioned it lists, under the same error:

`==17992==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==17992==    at 0x4F9F355: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)`

I just tried to run in debug mode and removing `-O3` and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.1.2, valgrind 3.5.0, CentOS 5.9 64 bit (but compiling with 32 bit flags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I feel dumb but the SSCCE thing pointed me in the right direction. I thought I'd looked at everything but hadn't. There was a setDebug() method in that class that could change the debug value, and it was getting called by the constructor a few levels down and passing in data from another structure that hadn't been initialized.